# Postgres COPY FROM Fails With invalid input syntax for type timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a pipe delimited file that I'm importing into Postgres (9.2.8) using the command:

```
COPY schema.tablename FROM '/path/to/file.csv' DELIMITERS '|' CSV
```

It has been working reliably for a while, but just choked on:

> Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "Sep 24 2013 12:00:00:000AM"

That looks like a valid timestamp to me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the last :000 that's messing you up.  For whatever reason, the timestamp-formatting gods decreed that milleseconds be delimited with a "." instead of a ":".

```
jberkus=# select timestamp 'Sep 24 2013 12:00:00:000AM';

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "Sep 24 2013 12:00:00:000AM"

jberkus=# select timestamp 'Sep 24 2013 12:00:00.000AM';

          timestamp      
    ---------------------
    2013-09-24 00:00:00
    (1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't change the 3rd party data, but I can at least scrub / fix it beforehand so it doesn't choke.